# Adding Jdbc sessions to spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When we add the JdbcSession to spring boot project , does it store the session directly in the database(I mean the relational database) . My assumption is If someone restarts the tomcat it should load all the sessions which were stored in the database.

I have added the following dependencies in the pom.xml , however I am not able to

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Still I do not get the @EnableJdbcJdbcHttpSession in eclipse.Is there any standard example currently I am referring to http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc.html#httpsession-jdbc-sample

I have not included the redis session in pom.xml but still I see session.redis when I do import in the eclipse.

Update 1 : 
My dependencies are like given below :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Remove `<type>pom</type>`... Also your web dependency should be pulled in by the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency. I would suggest the same for the session stuff.

Comment: What is <type> , I have added the updated dependencies.

Comment: Your dependencies are a bit messy. Remove the `spring-context-support` as that is already present as well as `spring-core`, `spring-jdbc` and `spring-security-web` and the slf4j dependencies.  You have the starters for those. Did you remove the `<type>` or didn't you have that? In the latter case add `<type>pom</type>` to your `spring-session-jdbc` dependency.

Comment: I have added <type>pom</type> in the pom.xml where spring-session-jdbc dependency exists . However I do not find the @EnableJdbcHttpSession is coming in the eclipse configuration , I have also removed the spring-context-support

Comment: Do you have proper maven integration in eclipse?

Comment: Yes , I have imported my project in eclipse as Maven project only , I can see every other dependency getting resolved but not for @EnableJdbcHttpSession

Comment: You tried both with and without the `type` element?

Comment: I would also like to know Does spring jdbc session supports persistence session data(With Mysql rdbms) , I have mentioned this in my question . If yes then why it is better than the traditional approach ?

Comment: Which traditional approach? Also have yu read up on what spring session is and what its intended use case is?

Comment: I have added the <type>pom</type> for sping-session-jdbc it is not working , I removed it is not working

Comment: If I say the traditional approach I mean the Using request and response of the HttpSession and creating the HttpSession using UUID and then authenticating the users.

Comment: As stated have you read the documentation as that answers your question(s).

Comment: I have read the documentation provided on this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc.html#httpsession-jdbc-sample , I do also find that it says about sessionRepositoryFilter , does it mean the sessions are persistent

Comment: What else would the use be of storing them in a database... That is quite persistent...

Comment: It is basically mapped with h2 database for persistence , how to change those mapping with the mysql

Comment: Why would it be mapped to h2, you have mysql as a driver in your pom.

Comment: I am referring to the example given in the above link

Comment: So... As long as your datasource is pointing to mysql it will be used. Don't confuse a sample with how everything is mapped by default.

Comment: I have added <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
but I do not see any class files in it , I can see only META-INF and Manifest files , I have never included redis spring session , still I can see them included in eclipse dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had struggled with this for a long time and found the solution:

The default version of spring-session used by spring framework 1.3.5.RELEASE is 1.0.2.RELEASE, which does not contain the @EnableJdbcHttpSession definition.

Solved this by:

Adding the session jar into the pom (make sure it uses the 1.2.0.RELEASE version):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you are using `build.gradle` then add `compile "org.springframework.session:spring-session"`